# How to deal with egotistical behaviour of colleagues in the workplace?

Tags: work-environment, company-culture, offices

I have seen this at every company: there are people who value themselves based on their designation and build a wall of ego and pride. They say things like "I know" or walk away without noticing you or saying hi or hello. I consider this egotistical and a big problem. It's not good for the workplace when it is done by those whose responsibility it is to control the environment in the office.

In my current workplace some employees who are more senior, higher-paid, or longer-serving bring their sense of self importance to conversations and feel the need to prove themselves right. Sometimes even they end up doing things wrong which affect others and then another employee - like me or someone else in my department - has to fix things.

How can I deal with such people while keeping the work going smoothly?

Comment: you need to be more specific in what question you are asking and maybe provide some info on the hierarchy of your current workplace

Comment: @Mike I updated it.

Comment: Hey San, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As @Mike pointed out, your question as-is is a bit difficult to follow. Could you please [edit] to be a bit more specific about what the problem is, and what you are looking for in a solution? For instance, *"How can I professionally correct errors my superiors make?"* or *"How can I get superiors to greet employees when they pass?"* or some other specific question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jmac I have updated the title I dont know if this is specific  or not I just want to know how to deal with not cool people at workplace.

Comment: Hey san, unfortunately if your question isn't specific, it is likely to be put [on hold](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) since it can't be effectively answered. Every workplace has people who are difficult to deal with, and there are [entire books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People) written on how to deal with them. I suggest reading a book if you want a general overview, and [edit]ing your question with a more specific question if you want good answers here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *How can I deal with such people while keeping the work going smoothly?*  - What aspects are you having trouble dealing with?  Are you trying to improve your communication with them? Improve their output quality?  What exactly are you having trouble doing with them.  If it is more than one thing it may need to be more than one question but lets try to identify them here first and then deal with that.

Comment: is there something to be fundamentally disagreed with what @san wrote? Maybe he has to refine his question a bit. Do you mean there are no egomaniacs to be found in any company? People will also have questions other than "can I bring candies to the meeting", "can i date my boss" etc. These are legitimate frustrations and asking to put on hold those questions immediately is a bit of a shame. Also you seem to suggest that just because he posed this question, he has a problem with his interpersonal skills in general and suggesting him to read HTWFAIP smacks an air of arrogance, sorry to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is not new, I have seen at every company, people value themselves
>   based on their designation and build a wall of ego and proud.

true, after all all companies are made of people, right? there are modest ones and arrogant ones. There will be super geniuses who do not know how to market themselves, there will be fools who always trying to get ahead at the expense of others

> I see ego is a big problem the phrases like "I know" or walking away
>   without noticing or saying hi or hello. not good at workplace, whose
>   responsibility it is to control the environment in office.

Yeah, great Steve Jobs had a name for these kind of people "[Bozos](http://www.forbes.com/sites/ericjackson/2012/01/31/why-every-company-needs-a-no-bozo-policy/)"

> Sometimes even they end up doing not right which affect others and
>   then an employee like me/ or other in my department has to fix things.

Remember, noone will give you power, you have to take it. Others they will often push you, manipulate you. [48 Laws of Power](http://www.amazon.de/48-Laws-Power-Robert-Greene/dp/0140280197/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1396949445&sr=1-1&keywords=48%20laws%20of%20power) is a good book - atleast it makes you aware of the treacherous path in the corporate world - also it is a wonderful read.

Comment: Please keep meta-commentary out of answers and remember to [be nice and considerate of others](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). I removed the meta-commentary to keep the focus on the content of your answer.

Comment: Just an FYI the downvotes were about the quality of the question not the content.